# Aggregation service implementation or how to send 2 000 000 requests efficiently?

Tags: python, concurrency, html-parsing

I am writing aggregation service. At this moment I need to parse ~2 000 000 pages. At first I tried to do this in Python, but soon I realized that it is not the right tool.

Now I think that it is probably good idea to fetch pages with another programming language and send responses through ZMQ to the Python back-end, where it will extract data and save it in the database.

So,

- How can I send 2 000 000 requests **FAST**? (Real-world examples, articles, etc.)
- Are there any better ways to implement aggregation service?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at 80legs: http://80legs.com/services.html

From their site:

> Setup your own web crawl in minutes and run it on over 50,000+ computers